# Intellij11 / Grails 2.0.1 Compilation Error "BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis'"

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, grails-2.0

I'm upgrading from grails 1.3.7 to 2.0.1 and am seeing an error in Intellij11. The compile/run-app work fine from the command line and running via Intellij produces the below error.
Environment: Max OS X 10.6.8, Java 1.6.0_29, IntelliJ11, Grails 2.0.1

```
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/Users/swall/.grails/2.0.1/projects/canoe-ux/plugins/resources-1.1.6/src/groovy/org/grails/plugin/resource/ProcessingFilter.groovy' Problem loading class javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:847)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:548)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:497)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.main(GroovycRunner.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem loading class javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner$7$1.loadClass(GroovycRunner.java:478)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToClass(ResolveVisitor.java:709)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:275)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromModule(ResolveVisitor.java:648)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:275)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:227)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:167)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1056)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1284)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$9.call(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:843)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:696)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:564)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner$7$1.loadClass(GroovycRunner.java:472)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove web-api.jar (or something JavaEE like that) from Grails library. Do you use IDEA 11 or 11.0.x? I'm asking because 11.0.x is supposed to do that automatically.

Comment: I'm using 11.0.2. I'll try looking for a jar to remove. Thx!

Comment: Works now!  - rm lib/javax/javaee-web-api/jars/javaee-web-api-6.0.jar

Comment: Has IDEA created this Grails library also in 11.0.2, or in 11.0?

Comment: I found the library under grails-2.0.1/lib.